# Storing value of a pointer in another pointer in Rust

Tags: pointers, rust

What is the best way to store a pointer as a value of another pointer?

I have a variable `ptr` that is of type `*mut u8`. How do I store the address that the `ptr` points to as the value of another pointer `t` that is also of type `*mut u8`.

I am trying to do something like

```
*t = ptr;
```

I get `expected u8, found *-ptr` error. I understand the address `ptr` will be 64 bits. I want to fill up 64 bits starting from address `t`.

Comment: Have you tried just assigning it?  `t = ptr`?

Comment: @DK. I am looking for a way to write the address that the `ptr` points to  to a specific location so that I can get the address even when I don't have `t`.

Comment: But that's what assignment *does*.  It takes the value of `ptr` (which is an address) and writes it to `t`, so that they're pointing to the same place in memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a variable `ptr` that is of type `*mut u8`. How do I store the address that the `ptr` points to as the value of another pointer `t` that is also of type `*mut u8`

Assign one pointer to another:

```
use std::ptr;

fn main() {
    let ptr: *mut u8 = ptr::null_mut();
    let t: *mut u8 = ptr;
}
```

`ptr` is a pointer and the address it points to is `NULL`. This value is now stored in the pointer `t` of the same type as `ptr`: `t` points to the address `NULL`.

```
+-----+        +-----+
|     |        |     |
| ptr |        |  t  |
|     |        |     |
+--+--+        +--+--+
   |              |
   |              |
   +---->NULL<----+
```

If you wanted to have `t` be a pointer to the *address of another pointer*, you would need to take a reference to `ptr`. The types also could not be the same:

```
use std::ptr;

fn main() {
    let ptr: *mut u8 = ptr::null_mut();
    let t: *const *mut u8 = &ptr;
}
```

```
+-----+      +-----+
|     |      |     |
|  t  +------> ptr +----->NULL
|     |      |     |
+-----+      +-----+
```

---

> I am looking for a way to write the address that the `ptr` points to to a specific location so that I can get the address even when I don't have `t`

Raw pointers have no compiler-enforced lifetimes associated with them. If you want to keep the address of something after the value has disappeared, that's an ideal case for them — you don't have to do anything:

```
use std::ptr;

fn do_not_dereference_this_result() -> *const u8 {
    let val: u8 = 127;
    let ptr: *const u8 = &val;
    ptr
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:p}", do_not_dereference_this_result())
}
```

In rarer cases, you might want to store the address in a `usize` (a pointer-sized integer value):

```
use std::ptr;

fn do_not_dereference_this_result() -> usize {
    let val: u8 = 127;
    let ptr: *const u8 = &val;
    ptr as usize
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:x}", do_not_dereference_this_result())
}
```

---

It *really* sounds like you are confused by how pointers work, which is a pretty good sign that you are going to shoot yourself in the foot if you use them. I'd **strongly** encourage you to solely use references in any *important* code until your understanding of pointers has increased.

Comment: I ended up declaring `ptr` and `t`  as ` *mut u64` and  did `*t = ptr as usize`. I imagine that will store ptr(address) at location of t.

Comment: @aupreti that's also incorrect. At the very least, it doesn't take into account different architectures with different pointer sizes.

Answer (score -1):

You generally don't want to do that, but I'll trust you know what you're doing.

The key here is to understand a few things:

- `Box<T>` is roughly equivalent to a `*T` allocated on the heap, you can use `Box::into_raw` to convert it into a `*T`.
- If you do this, you're effectively leaking the heap allocated `Box<T>`, because Rust no longer knows where it is, or tracks it. You must manually convert it back into a droppable object at some point, for example using `Box::from_raw`.
- You *must* `Box::new(...)` a value to ensure it is put on the heap, otherwise your raw pointer will point into the stack, which will eventually become invalid.
- Mutable aliasing (which means two `&mut T` pointing to the same data) causes undefined behavior. It is extremely important to understand that undefined behavior is not triggered by *concurrent writes* to mutable aliases... it is triggered by [mutable aliases *existing at the same time, in any scope*](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1447#issuecomment-185976431).

...but, if you really want to, you'd do it like this:

```
let foo_ref = Box::into_raw(Box::new(10));
let foo_ref_ref =  Box::into_raw(Box::new(foo_ref));

// Modify via raw pointer
unsafe {
    **(foo_ref_ref as *const *mut i32) = 100;
}

// Read via raw pointer 
unsafe {
    println!("{:?}", **foo_ref_ref);
}

// Resolve leaked memory
unsafe {
    Box::from_raw(foo_ref_ref);
    Box::from_raw(foo_ref);
}
```

Comment: A lot of unsafes, not a good way to go (this is not a part of your answer, but for people who might think: "Hey, this is a neat solution")
`#[deny(unsafe)]` all the things!

Comment: You don't need `transmute` for this *at all*; saying that "`Box<T>` is equivalent to a `*T`" is only barely accurate; you do not have to convert to a reference to modify data; the calls to `drop` are unneeded; the mention of a `Mutex` seems to come out left field (there are no threads here); and there's [disagreement about when mutable aliasing occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48882391/155423). Although there are some correct points in this answer, I cannot recommend that people use it unless they already know what they are doing (which isn't really the point of Stack Overflow).

Comment: At the very least, use `Box::into_raw` which is safe and isn't a transmute.

Comment: @JoshLee and `Box::from_raw`.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm happy to rewrite this answer to be better if there's a better way to write it, but I'm puzzled by some of your comments; why is `drop` not required? transmute consumes values, and those are heap allocated. They leak if you don't convert them back into droppables. I also have no idea what you're talking about with regard to modifying data without converting it to a reference, but that may just be my ignorance at play.

Comment: An explicit call to `drop` can be useful if the value isn't going out of scope but you still need to call the Drop impl. It's not considered idiomatic to call `drop` just to indicate that a value is being dropped. e.g. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6ca022edabba2536661bddeb6cbd06b3&version=stable. The fact that a `Box` is in scope tells you that of course a heap allocation will be freed.