# How can you modify the value in a raw pointer without converting it to a reference?

Tags: rust

In [Storing value of a pointer in another pointer in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143327/storing-value-of-a-pointer-in-another-pointer-in-rust/49143569?noredirect=1#comment85312759_49143569), it has been suggested that you can modify the value in a raw pointer in Rust without converting it to a reference (emphasis added):

> You don't need transmute for this at all; saying that "Box is equivalent to a *T" is only barely accurate; **you do not have to convert to a reference to modify data**; the calls to drop are unneeded; the mention of a Mutex seems to come out left field (there are no threads here); and there's disagreement about when mutable aliasing occurs. Although there are some correct points in this answer, I cannot recommend that people use it unless they already know what they are doing (which isn't really the point of Stack Overflow). – Shepmaster 10 hours ago

How can this be done?

Does it violate the mutable aliasing rules, and if not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a value into a raw pointer by dereferencing it and storing directly to it:

```
unsafe fn example(ptr: *mut u8) {
    *ptr = 42;
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = 0;
    unsafe { example(&mut a); }
    println!("{}", a);
}
```